# Opportunity Product updates is not firing Opportunity Trigger?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

We have a trigger on Opportunity, which always gets fired for any update in the child OpportunityLineItem records.

This works really well in all of my developer orgs, but in one of the client's UE(Unlimited Edition) org. The Opportunity trigger is only fired for a change in the following field:

"OpportunityLineItem->Unit Price"

Though the Opportunity trigger fires well, on any field change in OpportunityLineItem in my dev org.

What could be reason for this behavioural difference here ?

Comment: are that environments absolutely similar? including workflows and processes ?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy, I tried to check it by deactivating all workflows/flows/process builders in the org but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: The client's price books may be set up and configured differently. They could also be using some kind of CPQ add-on like Apptus that would change the expected behavior.

Comment: @crmprogdev Checked the pricebook section as well but didn't find any change there.

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior,

Everytime you update the "UnitPrice" or "Quantity" standard fields on the OpportunityLineItem, the total opportunity amount or quantity get updated, hence triggering the opportunity's update trigger.

Any change on the other OpportunityLineItem fields (for example line description) has no effect on the parent opportunity therefore the opportunity update trigger is not fired.

You must check closely which fields you are updating on the line items. if these are custom fields you must look at triggers or processes related to your OpportunityLineItem object.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same that total price updates can only trigger the updates to the parent opportunity but I was wrong as when I checked it in the dev org. Every oli field updates (either it is unit price or description) firing the trigger on the parent opportunitg so still uncertain why it is not happening in the client's sandbox!

Comment: Anyway, now I resolved it in the sandbox via Opportunitylineitem trigger where I am performing blank updates to the parent opportunity to call parent opportunity trigger explicitly.